# How can I compare two classes base their methods?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to find out the missing properties in one class by comparing the other class

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTO
{

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

}
```

Above I should get the output like "UserID, "LastName" properties are missing in UserDTO.

Comment: Why would it not output `UserID` as missing, too?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? This is trivial.

Comment: Yes, question updated.

Comment: @RockySingh I edited your title. If it looks wrong, please feel free to update it.

Answer (score 10):

```
var list = typeof(User).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name)
           .Except(typeof(UserDTO).GetProperties().Select(y => y.Name))
           .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Including suggestions in comments and public `Fields`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Diff(Type t1, Type t2)
{
    return t1.GetProperties().Select(p1 => new { Name = p1.Name, Type = p1.PropertyType })
            .Concat(t1.GetFields().Select(f1 => new { Name = f1.Name, Type = f1.FieldType }))
            .Except(t2.GetProperties().Select(p2 => new { Name = p2.Name, Type = p2.PropertyType })
                    .Concat(t2.GetFields().Select(f2 => new { Name = f2.Name, Type = f2.FieldType })))
            .Select(a => a.Name);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution +1.

Comment: +1. You can even contain it in a generic method like `IEnumerable<string> GetDiff<TSrc, TDst>()` if there's a need to reuse it :)

Comment: I would add the type  `.Select(p => new { Name = p.Name, Type = p.PropertyType });`. Then you would realize if the properties would have the same name but different types.

Comment: This will kill the `Except()` functionality unless you either make your anonymous type into a proper type with an overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` function, or you supply it with a special `EqualityComparer`. By default it will now do an `object.Equals()` which compares object references rather than values, thus every property will be shown as different.

Comment: @WillemDuncan No, anonymous types are compared by their properties(If all properties' values are equal then anynymous types are equal). Try and see `bool b = new { a = 1 }.Equals(new { a = 1 });`

Comment: Am never too old to learn, thanks! Probably when I tried I was storing some complex values inside the anonymous types, breaking the equality comparer on a different level.

Answer (score 7):

Use reflection to get the properties, see [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx). Then compare both property lists to find the missing ones.

```
var UserProperties = typeof(User).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
var UserDTOProperties = typeof(UserDTO).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);

var missingProperties = UserProperties.Except(UserDTOProperties);
```

Take into account that all inherited properties will also be present in these lists, unless yous specify `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to the `GetProperties()` method, see [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).